# In Kotlin is there a way to initialize the superclass after some operations?

Tags: android, kotlin

This is probably very basic, but I can't seem to find a way to initialize a superclass with generated values.
For example, I want to inflate a view and then pass it to the superclass RecyclerView.ViewHolder.

In Swift I would do something like this:

```
class CustomViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    init(json: JSON) {
        let view = getView(json)
        super.init(view)
    }
}
```

Is there a similar way in Kotlin? Or do I have to get the View outside and then pass it to both the CustomViewHolder and the RecyclerView.ViewHolder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can i.e. call a function from companion object:

```
class CustomViewHolder(json: JSON) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(getView(json)) {
    companion object {
        private fun getView(json: JSON): View {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also declare it as a top-level function. May be more clear if its definition  is before the class, depending on circumstances.